# Determine whether the relation is reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, and/or transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Determine whether the relation R on the set of all Web pages is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and/or transitive, where (a, b) ∈ R if and only if

a) everyone who has visited Web page a has also visited Web page b.

b) there are no common links found on both Web page a and Web page b.

c) there is at least one common link on Web page a and Web page b.

d) a is taller than b.

e) a and b were born on the same day.

f) a has the same first name as b.

I have the knowledge about the reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, and transitive also I can able to solve the problems when the  relations are defined in ordered pairs. But can't able to visualize this kind of relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) is reflexive because everyone who has visited web page $a$ has also visited web page $a$. It is not symmetric because if everyone who has visited web page $a$ has visited web page $b$, this does not mean that everyone who has visited web page $b$ has also visited web page $a$. It is also not antisymmetric, because if everyone who has visited web page $a$ has visited web page $b$ and everyone has visited web page $b$ has visited web page $a$, it does not necessarily mean that $a$ and $b$ are the same web page. It is transitive because if everyone who has visited web page $a$ also has visited web page $b$ and everyone who has visited web page $b$ also has visited web page $c$, then it follows that everyone who has visited web page $a$ has also visited web page $c$.

b) is not transitive because even though there are no common links found on web page $a$ and web page $b$ and there are no common links found on web page $b$ and web page $c$, there may still be common links found on web page $a$ and $c$.

d) is not reflexive, because $a$ can not be taller than itself.

f) is symmetric, because if $a$ has the same first name as $b$, then $b$ also has the same first name as $a$.

I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I got the concept.